# What Order Do Java Methods Run In?

Tags: java, class

**I MEANT THE FUNCTIONS, SORRY!**

With the following code, it has a few classes that do separate jobs.
The question is, since they never call each other, which order do they run in?

Do they run at the same time?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Moving extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    int x, y;
    Timer timer;

    Moving() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        timer = new Timer(10, this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x += 1;
        y += 1;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (x > 1080 && y > 880) {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        } else {
            g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Moving");
        f.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Moving m = new Moving();
        f.add(m);
        f.setSize(1100, 900);
        f.setVisible(true);
        m.timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: your question doesn't make much sense as it is - there's only one class, for example.  can you add more details?

Comment: **I meant the functions, sorry.**

Comment: It makes no sense to ask about the order in which classes run.  Classes don't "run", threads run and execute methods.  The order in which methods get executed is determined by may things, including the order of calls in your main method and external events (in an event-driven program).

Comment: No, you meant *methods*, sorry. Java has no "functions".

Comment: This is a very confusing question because you are leaving out a lot of detail and are assuming that we understand the things you're not telling us. Please correct this soon, else this question is liable to be closed.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Is that a real distinction? Methods vs functions?

Comment: @trutheality: Well it is at least syntactically, especially since he made a point to correct his correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean methods, and not classes.  Furthermore, the order of operations is determined by the order in which you call them, ala the `main` method.  In your example, you are only calling the `Moving` constructor, so that is the only "method" in your class that will be executed.  The others are defined, but will not run since they are not called (at least not in the code you provided).

Update (thanks dacwe and cHao):
Sorry, I am not familiar with JPanel and was not aware of the methods that are called outside of this class.  In this case, the `repaint()` method will indirectly call `paintComponent()`, meanwhile, the Timer will set off a call to [actionPerformed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).  [This post](http://beginwithjava.blogspot.com/2008/07/controlling-javas-graphics.html) does a good job of explaining it in some more detail.

Also, as a note--Java typically calls its "verbs" methods.  Partially a convention of most OO languages, partially because the function is tied to a class, so it merits that distinction.  Javascript, a functional language, calls its verbs "functions".

Comment: The `paintComponent` method will be called by the EDT and the timer will execute the `actionaPerformed` method...

Comment: As will `actionPerformed`, assuming the code compiles and runs; `main` ends up starting the timer.

Comment: @GrailsGuy The `actionPerformed` will be called in intervals of 10 milliseconds by the `Timer`

Answer (score 0):

Your program executes in the following order:

1. `main` entry point
2. `Moving` contructor
3. `Timer` constructor
4. `Timer.start()` method of the `Timer` class
5. `Moving.actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` gets called every 10 milliseconds

Comment: 3.5: `paintComponent` gets triggered by `setVisible` in main.  5a:  `paintComponent` gets triggered by the `repaint` in `actionPerformed`.

Comment: @cHao Indeed, did not want to go into those fine grained details :)